# Is there a way to change the model on a Blazor EditForm Component depending on user selection?

Tags: inheritance, blazor

I have a class called Client and two classes that inherit from it ClientCompany and ClientPerson, I have a blazor EditForm to add an edit clients and depeding on the type of client the user chooses (Company or Person) I would like to bind the form and the controls to the corresponding class and its properties.

I want to do this on the same form because the parent class Client has a lot of fields but ClientCompany and ClientPerson only a few so if I create two diferent blazor components for each class I would be repeating code.

So I would like to know If Is there a way to change the binding model for the EditForm and their controls depending on a a radiobutton selection, so if user selects Person bind the EditForm to ClientPerson but  if the user selects Company bind the EditForm to ClientCompany.

I'm using .net 5, Blazor Web Assembly and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<EditForm EditContext="@EditContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">

</EditForm>

@code
{
    private EditContext EditContext;
    private Client client= new Client() { };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(client);

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can initially initialize the EditContext object with an instance of the Client class, and when your user make a choice, you can initialize the EditContext instance with a new instance of EditContext, like this:

```
ClientCompany client= new ClientCompany () { };

EditContext = new EditContext(client);
```

Comment: Thank you Enet for your help I really appreciate it. I tried to apply your suggestion, but when I want to access the Model properties on ValidSubmit, they are null. I guess It has to do with the way I'm binding the controls, what I'm doing is this. `code` <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit"> <InputText ID="name" @bind-Value="@client.Name"></InputTextBox> </EditForm> protected void HandleValidSubmit() { ClientCompany clientC = EditContext.Model as ClienteCompany; } All properties on EditContext.Model are null. Thank you

Comment: Of course they are null...what do you expect them to be ? If you entered values into the EditForm's controls, and then you create a new instance of the  EditContext object with a new ClientCompany, the previous entered data is lost. You should call  the HandleValidSubmit method before you reset the value of EditContext. Indeed, you can place the resetting of the EditContext object in the HandleValidSubmit method to prevent the use from click once again on the "submit" button, an action that can result in unwanted attempt to add the same data to a database.

Comment: I'm sorry Enet I don´t get it. The first time the form is empty and the EditContext object is Client, then the user selects ClientCompany or ClientPerson, when the selection happens I change de EditContext to ClientCompany or ClientPerson, then the user fills the controls with data, then he clicks on save data and on the HandleValidSubmit I took the data and I want to save it. But when I try to access the data everything is null.

Comment: post complete repo of your code. Don't miss anything...

Comment: Hi Enet, I found the problem, It was on the event where the user make the choice, `ClientCompany client= new ClientCompany () { }; EditContext = new EditContext(client);`, this was creating a local variable client and was not binding to the control, so I use this instead `client= new ClientCompany ()`, and the binding works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Note that when creating a new EditContext for your EditForm, you will not only loose all previous defined state and values, you will also loose your defined Validators. This is not expected behaviour I find, because now I have to re-add my validators in code behind.